# Configuring Celery on SourceLair

Tags: django, celery

## AIM

I have a Django project on a Cloud IDE (SourceLair). Following [a guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html), I am attempting to config Celery as part of my app.

## CODE

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
```

## ERROR

```
[2018-08-22 16:03:43,059: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

Comment: `CELERY_BROKER_URL =  'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'` could you use this url? Define the port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SourceLair support, I learned the problem was that SourceLair doesn't support RabbitMQ. Instead, I've successfully config Celery using SQS.

The full message:

> The reason this is not working is because the CELERY_BROKER_URL you
>   provided is using RabbitMQ as the underlying message queue. RabbitMQ
>   cannot be used on SourceLair at all, but there are a couple of
>   alternatives for you:
>
> You can use the Redis Broker via SourceLair's Redis add-on (currently
>   in private mode, for $5 per month after 1 week of free trial) You can
>   use Amazon SQS which has a free tier available

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you have missed mentioning the port on which RabbitMQ is running.

Could you try to modify in the settings.py file `CELERY_BROKER_URL` to this

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'
```